# (gmail gadget) I don't know where to publish my spec to a public location

Tags: location, gmail, manifest, specifications

I am trying to write a gadget for gmail. I need to write a spec and a manifest for my gadget. Then, the Google documentation says:

"Publish the gadget spec to a location which is accessible on the public Internet. An intranet will not work. Your hard drive will not work. (Why? Google's servers need to download the gadget. If they can't reach it, then Gmail can't display it.)"

https://developers.google.com/gmail/contextual_gadgets

Does anyone have any idea of how I might be able to do publish code in the public Internet ? What steps should I follow in order to do it ?

Thanks a lot for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to put a XML file on the internet where Google's servers can access it. There's more ways to do this than I can possibly mention in a single reply. Search for basic web hosting and then you'll have to FTP to your server to put the file up there. Some services, like Dropbox, also allow you to make files public so if you didn't want to use a hosting provider you could go that route.